# How to POST data from a dropdown list populated by MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

Before anyone flames, I have looked at many more than just the following 3 posts. None of these have working answers.

[How to Post data from a php database populated Drop Down to another script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296892/how-to-post-data-from-a-php-database-populated-drop-down-to-another-script)

[Passing value from a dropdown list from one php to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16220721/passing-value-from-a-dropdown-list-from-one-php-to-another)

[What is the best way to have a dynamic dropdownlist in PHP and POST selected value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614270/what-is-the-best-way-to-have-a-dynamic-dropdownlist-in-php-and-post-selected-val)

These simply just do. not. work.

Now on to my question:

I have a dropdown list on my php page that is being populated by a MySQL query. This part works perfectly. However -- I can not get the selected value from the dropdown list to post in to my next PHP script.

My code on "page1.php":

```
    Please select your dietary preference: 


    <form method="post" action="page2.php">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="dropdown_value">
                    <?php foreach ($data as $row): ?>
                        <option><?=$row["dietary_option"]?></option>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </form>
```

This successfully populates my dropdown list with the available dietary options pulled from my database.

And on page2.php:

```
    $mealSelection = $_POST["dropdown_value"];
```

Simply does nothing. It yields no value(?). Echoing $mealSelection seemingly echoes nothing. It is blank.

I would ultimately like to use $mealSelection in a new query on page2.php but I can't seem to retrieve the selected value from page1.

Any wizards with some insight?

Thanks for taking the time to look at my issue here.

LC-Data

Edit: None of the answers for simply posting dropdown options from predefined HTML work. I specifically need the dropdown to be populated from my db.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using $\_POST to get select option value from HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139501/using-post-to-get-select-option-value-from-html)

Comment: Place value attribute to option tags. Than let us know ?

Comment: Thanks Adnan, good eye. Amit below was able to correctly identify that as well. This was indeed what was holding me back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
<?php foreach ($data as $row): ?>
         <option value="<?= $row['dietary_option'] ?>"><?=$row["dietary_option"]?></option>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

You haven't given `value` field in your `options`. Without `value` field, it won't work.

Comment: Hey Amit, I will be momentarily selecting yours as the correct answer. What a horrible oversight! Thanks for taking the time to debug that.